# Highstock : altered points?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

(Translated by Google )

I have a chart that works well , if the amount of points is low (or show only part with zoom) . But in the example, there are more than 5000 and does not look good.

```
$(function () {

  data = load();

  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x'
    },

    rangeSelector: { enabled: false },

    navigator: { enabled: false },

    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
       dateTimeLabelFormats: {
         second: '%d/%m/%y',
         minute: '%d/%m/%y',
         hour: '%d/%m/%y',
         day: '%d/%m/%y',
         week: '%d/%m/%y',
         month: '%d/%m/%y',
         year: '%d/%m/%y'
       },
     },

     yAxis: {
          opposite: false,
          gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
          gridLineColor: '#CCCCCC',
          min: -1,
          max: 2,
          labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              var lab = ['No OK', 'OK'];
              return lab[this.value] || '';
            }
          }
         },

    series : [{
      name : 'test',
      turboThreshold: 6000,
      marker : {
        enabled : true,
        radius : 2,
        symbol: 'circle'
      },
      data : data      
    }]
  });

});


function load(){
    return [
     {"x":1420167601000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167602000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167603000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167604000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167605000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167606000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167607000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167608000,"y":0},
     {"x":1420167609000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167610000,"y":1},
     {"x":1420167611000,"y":0},
     {"x":1420167612000,"y":1},
     ...
     ... an so on ( for one year points ~5000 items ) ....
     ... 95% of them are 1. 5% of them are 0 ...
     ...
   ];
}
```

[fiddle > Complete example](http://goo.gl/ILz145)

The series can only have values ​​0 or 1

However , you can see that in the graph, look like 0.9

Why?
I need to respect the value of 0 and 1

Comment: Please put the code in your question.

Comment: Yes, but websites/fiddles/user accounts disappear. If the code is here it will be left here to help folks in the future who could use this for an answer.

Comment: I understood now...sorry

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the answer .

The problem is the serie.dataGrouping configuration.

In my case, I need it to stay disabled, or enabled with approximation = low

Then:

```
...
series : [{
  name : 'test',
  turboThreshold: 6000,
  dataGrouping: { enabled: false },
  marker : {
    enabled : true,
    radius : 2,
    symbol: 'circle'
  },
  data : data      
}]
...
```